# C++ Builder RAD Studio XE7 change color of a Panel

Tags: c++, c++builder, tpanel

After pushing a button I wanted to change the color of a panel to green:

```
ErrorDetectorPanel->Brush->Color = clLime;
```

doesn´t work.

```
ErrorDetectorPanel->Color = clLime;
ErrorDetectorPanel->Refresh();
```

doesn´t work.

with this addiction:

```
ErrorDetectorPanel->ParentColor = false;
ErrorDetectorPanel->Refresh();
```

it still doesn´t work.

tried it this way:

```
HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0));
SetWindowLong(ErrorDetectorPanel->Handle,WM_ERASEBKGND, 0);
SetWindowLong(ErrorDetectorPanel->Handle,GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG)brush);
```

TForm transparency is false
same result after pushing the button.

How can I do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use

```
TPanel *tp[]={Panel454,Panel455,Panel456};

    for(int i=sizeof(tp)/sizeof(tp[0]);--i>=0;){
        tp[i]->ParentBackground=false;
        tp[i]->StyleElements = TStyleElements(); // disable all
//      tp[i]->CleanupInstance();
        tp[i]->Color=clSkyBlue;
        }
```

if the Themed/Styled controls used.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `TPanel.Color` property is the correct solution (it will automatically set `ParentColor` to false), however you have to disable theming/styling on the `TPanel` (or the entire program as a whole) in order to use custom coloring. Themed/Styled controls get their coloring from the active theme/style.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I didn´t use any theming/styling, so what else could cause the problem?

Comment: Application theming is enabled by default.

Comment: Tried this site: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/disablethemes_xml.html still doesn´t work. You got some steps how to fix it?